# Removing apostrophe in result set

Tags: db2, replace

```
create view ENTRP_SERVS.V_IRS_BULK as
Select 
  Atr.Ssn_Tx
,Names.First_Na
,Names.Middle_Na
,Names.Last_Na
,Reff.Ref_Cd_Desc_Tx Suffix_Na
,MBR.PRSN_MBRSH_ID,
T_PRSN_MBRSH_TAX.FILTER_TYPE_CD

 From Hix.T_Enrt En Inner Join Hix.T_Prsn_Enrt Pe On En.Enrt_Id = Pe.Enrt_Id And En.Enrt_Status_Cd In (428,439, 430 ) And Pe.Active_In = 'Y' And (Pe.Retro_In Is Null Or Pe.Retro_In = 'N') 
Left Outer Join Hix.T_Aptc Ap On En.Enrt_Id = Ap.Enrt_Id
Left Outer Join Hix.T_Prsn_Addl_Attr Atr On Pe.Prsn_Mbrsh_Id = Atr.Prsn_Mbrsh_Id 
Left Outer Join
    (
                    Select nAc.Prsn_mbrsh_Id,  First_Na , Middle_Na , Last_Na, Suffix_Cd From Hix.T_Prsn_Name Na, Hix.t_prsn_mbrsh_prsn_name_ac nAc
                                                   where na.prsn_name_id = nAc.prsn_Name_Id
    ) Names On Pe.prsn_mbrsh_id = Names.prsn_mbrsh_id
Left Outer Join Hix.T_Ref_Data Reff On Names.Suffix_Cd = Reff.Ref_Data_Id
Left Outer Join Hix.T_Ref_Data Re On Atr.GENDER_CD = Reff.Ref_Data_Id
Left Outer Join Hix.T_PRSN_MBRSH MBR on MBR.PRSN_MBRSH_ID =  Pe.PRSN_MBRSH_ID

Left Outer Join

(SELECT (CASE WHEN FILLING_STATUS_CD IN (2061,2062,2063) OR  (FILLING_STATUS_CD=2063 AND PRIM_TX_FILER_IN ='Y') THEN 'PRIMARY'
             WHEN FILLING_STATUS_CD=2063 AND PRIM_TX_FILER_IN ='N' THEN 'SPOUSE'
             WHEN FILLING_STATUS_CD IN (2066, 2068) THEN 'DEPENDENT'
             ELSE NULL
             END) AS FILTER_TYPE_CD,PRSN_MBRSH_ID FROM HIX.T_PRSN_MBRSH_TAX  WHERE TAX_FL_YR_NB=YEAR(CURRENT DATE)-2)T_PRSN_MBRSH_TAX
    ON PE.PRSN_MBRSH_ID=T_PRSN_MBRSH_TAX.PRSN_MBRSH_ID WHERE T_PRSN_MBRSH_TAX.FILTER_TYPE_CD IS NOT NULL
```

I have this view and I want to remove the apostrophe (') from the FIRST_NA, MIDDLE_NA and LAST_NA columns. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE` function, e.g.

```
select replace(yourfield,'''','') from yourtable where ...
```

Here we are replacing a single quote character with an empty string. Since SQL character literals are themselves enclosed in single quotes, we escape the single quote character *in the literal* by doubling it.

More information about the use of the `REPLACE` function can be found [in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000843.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-122&lang=en), as is often the case.

Comment: I just edited the question. Can you please answer it now? Thanks :)

Comment: What seems unclear in my answer?

Comment: The two fields after NAME in the Resplace function and also the "values" keyword. And its specific to one valueONEIL. But i am retrieving more than 1000 records in my view.

Answer (score 0):

what about you do something using the `replace` function alongside the `char(39)` character just like in the example below:

```
declare @the_string nvarchar(100) = 'His Name is James O''Brian'
select @the_string
select REPLACE(@the_string, char(39), '')
```

this will give you the following result:

[image]